# Integral of $\ln^2(x^2-1)/x^4$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I need to solve the following indefinite integral:
$$\int \frac{\log^2(x^2-1)}{x^4}dx.$$  ($\log$ is the natural log)
It's a past paper question from my uni exam so I don't think the answer is as complicated as WolframAlpha [gives](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint+%5Cfrac%7Blog%5E2%28x%5E2-1%29%7D%7Bx%5E4%7Ddx&dataset=).
Please help guys :)

Comment: $+1$ or $-1$ in the log ?

Comment: sorry, -1 in the log

Comment: As you have logarithm *squared*, you probably have no choice but to go for $u=\log (x^2-1)$, or even the entire square. However, I don't think you can avoid $Li$ function, unless Wolfram forgot to simplify.

Comment: Yep, it seems like I'm getting something that resembles what Wolfram gave me - and in the end I have to integrate $\int{\frac{log(x+1)}{x-1}}$ and $\int{\frac{log(x-1)}{x+1}}$ which I can't integrate and Wolfram gives those two integrals as $Li$ functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Start by integrating by parts with $u=\log^2(x^2-1)$ and $dv=\frac{1}{x^4}dx$. Then,

$$\int\frac{\log^2(x^2-1)}{x^4}dx=-\frac{\log^2(x^2-1)}{3x^3}+\frac43\int\frac{\log(x^2-1)}{x^2(x^2-1)}dx.$$

Comment: Indeed, that's how I went about solving it. The problem was the $Li$ function that's a part of the solution later which we haven't learnt but after checking with my lecturer it turns out to be a mistype in the original exam question.

Answer (score 0):

take $log(x^2-1)$=t
after substituting you get
$$\int \frac{t^2e^t}{(e^t+1)^{5/2}}dt$$
write it as
$$\int \frac{t^2(e^t+1-1)}{(e^t+1)^{5/2}}dt.$$
you get two integrals
$$\int \frac{1}{2}t^2(e^t+1)^{-3/2}dt+\int \frac{1}{2}t^2(e^t+1)^{-5/2}dt$$
i think you can go from here by parts

Comment: Tried going that route, it doesn't  work because you can't integrate $(e^t+1)^{-3/2}$ so that has to be your $u$ which means you'll just keep increasing ppwers of those expressions.